# perl regex to find pid value, and certain phrase from a linux command result?

Tags: regex, perl, extract

This code from linux command line:

```
perl -e 'my $serviceInfo = `ssh servername1 /sbin/service service1 status`; $serviceInfo1 =~ /(pid *)/; print $serviceInfo;'
```

...puts the results into variable $serviceInfo, and prints these possible messages:

```
service1 (pid  22630) is running...
service1 (pid  14039) is stopped...
service1 dead but pid file exists
```

I need to extract the pid # and "is running", or "is stopped"; or "dead but pid file exists" for the service in question - ultimately to use the pid# in a variable when looking at the process table [to determine if the job is running], and each of the messages, "is running", "is stopped", etc. in a variable for making decisions on where to go depending on if the service is running or not. I don't know when to use regex vs grep vs awk, etc. Going through regex tutorials hoping it will "stick" soon!

Help? Ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: show what output you want for each of those errors?

Comment: output desired is simply putting into a variable the pid #, then the text afterwards like "is running", "is stopped", or "dead but pid file exists" each into a variable. i will use the pid# against a process table to determine if the job is running, and store the other messages in a history table.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing :

```
perl -e '
    $_ = qx(ssh servername1 /sbin/service service1 status);
    print $1, $2 if /(pid\s+\d+)\)(\s*is\s+\w+)/
'
```

Output:

```
pid  22630 is running
pid  14039 is stopped
pid  14039 is stopped
```

I hope that's what's you expect. If not, please clarify your original POST.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems.  First, this:

```
$serviceInfo1 =~ /(pid *)/;
```

performs a match against $serviceInfo1, which hasn't been set.  You presumably want to match against $serviceInfo and assign the captured part to $serviceInfo1.  That looks like this:

```
($serviceInfo1) = $serviceInfo =~ /(pid *)/;
```

or this:

```
$serviceInfo1 = ( $serviceInfo =~ /(pid *)/ )[0];
```

Second, your regex is capturing "pid" and zero or more spaces; to capture just the number too do this:

```
my $pid = ( $serviceInfo =~ /\(pid *([0-9]+)\)/ )[0] || '';
```

You could capture the state (dead, running, or stopped) like this:

```
my $state = ( $serviceInfo =~ / (dead|(?<= is )running|(?<= is )stopped)/ )[0] || 'unknown';
```

and then

```
print "state $state pid $pid\n";
```